# Django rest framework user registration?

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am following [this tutorial](http://richardtier.com/2014/02/25/django-rest-framework-user-endpoint/comment-page-1/#comment-39) but facing these problems I can't fix:

1. Upon registering user, I can not log in with that user to the api because the password is not hashed
   "Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm." in admin
2. I cannot post to 'api/accounts' or see the form in the browseable api when I am not logged in to the api

My code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
        write_only_fields = ('password',)

    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        # call set_password on user object. Without this
        # the password will be stored in plain text.
        user = super(UserSerializer, self).restore_object(attrs, instance)
        user.set_password(attrs['password'])  #somehow not hashing
        return user
```

Comment: In DRF 3.0, `write_only_fields = ('password',)` is changed to `extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}, }`

Comment: Another good solution :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27468552/changing-serializer-fields-on-the-fly/#answer-27471503

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that set_password() does NOT save the object and since you have called the super first, your object is already saved with raw password.

Just simply use post_save() to save the password.

```
def post_save(self, obj, created=False):
    """
    On creation, replace the raw password with a hashed version.
    """
    if created:
        obj.set_password(obj.password)
        obj.save()
```

Answer (score 13):

I tried the accepted answer in DRF 3.0.2 and it didn't work. The password was not being hashed.

Instead, override the create method in your model serializer

```
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(email=validated_data['email'], username=validated_data['username'])
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

This hashes the password when you create a user using the rest framework, not post_save

Comment: It might be easier to user `User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)` to create the user (with hashed password) rather than doing it in two lines

Answer (score 6):

Another approach for DRF 3.X:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

    def create(self, validated_data):    
        if validated_data.get('password'):
            validated_data['password'] = make_password(
                validated_data['password']
            )

        user = get_user_model().objects.create(**validated_data)

        return user
```

Comment: you are perfect

Answer (score 3):

I've used [wsgeorge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27886026/2752041)'s solution to build my own. A blank `User` object is created just so I can use `.set_password()`:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    user = User()
    user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
    validated_data['password'] = user.password
    return super(UserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

Different from his answer, I do not save the user myself. I leave that to the parent class calling `super`.

Answer (score 0):

Override create of model serialzier

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        if validated_data.get('password'):
            validated_data['password'] = make_password(validated_data['password'])
        return super(UserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

Be sure to import

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
```

Answer (score -1):

We can write a signal in User to solve this.

```
def create_hash(sender, instance=None, *args, **kwargs):
passwd = instance.password
instance.set_password(passwd)


pre_save.connect(create_hash, sender=User)
```