# Django REST framework - How to create a UserSerializer object but not return the password?

Tags: django, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework, user-registration

I am using the built in User model located in

```
django.contrib.auth.models
```

This is my serialiers.py file:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', )
```

Now, what I want is that when I serialize a User object like so:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
serialzer=UserSerializer(user)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

I only want to return the "username" as a JSON object to the front-end (I don't want to return the password). This works fine, but when I try to create a user object using this view:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def users(request):
    """
    Create a new user.
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The User object can be created without the user inputting a password (I tried doing

```
curl -X POST localhost:8000/user -d "username=testUser"
# the above URL (localhost:8000/user) calls the "users" view
```

and it successfully created a user with only the username given). How do I make it so that when creating a user, it only successfully creates the user when a valid username and password is given (because a valid username and password is required for the "User" model located in django.contrib.auth.models)?

Answer (score -1):

Pop it from the returned success response

```
serializer.data.pop('password', None)
```

I forget if data is serialized before or after response, if it is serialized before, then make sure to use json library to convert, remove password key, reserialize, then send.

Comment: when I use that line of code, it first gives me an error saying that pop only takes 1 argument. I remove "None" and tried "serializer.data.pop('password')" and now it is giving me a TypeError saying "ExceptionValue: object cannot be interpreted as an integer".

Comment: Ignoring the fact that this doesn't work, it still opens the door to revealing the hash if someone forgets to pop it off of the data before it is passed back. You should be using a `write_only` field, like I explained in [the duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27468552/359284).

Comment: Nice didn't know there was that option on password, my solution does work if you dump data to python then reserialize but works doesn't mean good practice gj.